# Call analogue to the property decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a **call** analogue to the @property decorator?

As a matter of personal taste, when communicating to remote hardware, I like to set/get their state as follows:

```
remote_controller_state()          # Returns the state
remote_controller_state(arg)       # Sets controller state
```

Property decorators are really handy for minimizing code when using the attribute equivalent:

```
remote_controller_state         # Returns current state
remote_controller_state = arg   # Sets remote controller state
```

Here's how I currently code these.  I would definitely like to get rid of the extra boilerplate:

```
def remote_controller_state(self, state_arg=None):
    if arg is None: return self._get_remote_controller_state()
    else: return self._set_remote_controller_state(arg)

def _get_remote_controller_state(self):
    state = <complex comms with remote controller>
    return state

def _set_remote_controller_state(self, state):
    <complex comms with remote controller>(state)
```

Comment: Your personal taste is in conflict with Guido's, so Python is not trying to help you here. But you could write your own descriptor to do this; see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: @zmccord True on both accounts